# Sorting in select as well as aggregating - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have used this in a NoSql database, but now I need similar in SQL Server if possible.

I have following data:

| ID | Code | Created | Comment | Priority |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 'CodeA' | 2021-07-11 23:02:01 | 343 | 1 |
| 2 | 'CodeB' | 2021-07-11 23:02:01 | 3212 | 2 |
| 1 | 'CodeD' | 2021-07-11 23:02:02 | sdad3a | 3 |
| 1 | 'CodeA' | 2021-07-11 23:02:03 | 344 | 2 |
| 1 | 'CodeA' | 2021-07-11 23:02:00 | 345 | 3 |
| 2 | 'CodeE' | 2021-07-11 23:02:03 | Null | 4 |
| 1 | 'CodeB' | 2021-07-11 23:02:03 | 346 | 3 |

I would like to group by `ID` and:

1. have a column `Date` containing value from `Created` sorted by `priority desc` and `Created asc` but only if `Code = 'A'` or `Code = 'CodeP'`
2. have another column `Comment` sorted by `Priority asc, created asc` only for code `'CodeB'`

etc.

For example for id = 1:

```
Id   Date                 Comment
-------------------------------------    
1   2021-07-11 23:02:00   |346
```

Currently I have started to try using groupBy + case clause in select clause but I am wondering if there is better way?

I have working solution with derived queries in the select for every column but that is neither smart and the query becomes very slow due to multiple queries as well as sometimes I need to further process data which requires another query and longer time fx.

I need to process the field comment in relation to different type of values so I am not happy with this approach currently.

PS: working solution is using derived table I believe its called or subquery in select:

```
select 
    id, 
    (select top 1 created 
     from tableA 
     where Code = 'CodeA' or Code = 'CodeP' 
     order by Priority desc, created asc) as Date,
    (select top 1 comment 
     from tableA 
     where Code = 'CodeA' or Code = 'CodeP' 
     order by Priority asc, created desc) as Comment
etc..
```

Comment: What is your "working solution", please [edit] your question

Comment: edited and added a bit more info as well as edited the examples in the table

Answer (score 1):

You can use `FIRST_VALUE` in a derived table, then `GROUP BY` on the outside.

I'm assuming here that you don't want any other results than those `CodeA/CodeP` rows

```sql
SELECT
    t.ID,
    [Date] = MIN([Date]),
    Comment = MIN(Comment)
FROM (
    SELECT *,
        [Date] = FIRST_VALUE(t.Created) OVER (PARTIION BY t.ID ORDER BY t.Priority DESC, t.Created ASC
                   ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLOWING),
        [Comment] = FIRST_VALUE(t.Comment) OVER (PARTIION BY t.ID ORDER BY t.Priority ASC, t.Created ASC
                   ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLOWING)
    FROM tableA t
    WHERE t.Code IN ('CodeA', 'CodeP')
) t
GROUP BY t.ID;
```

You can also use `ROW_NUMBER` to the same effect

```sql
SELECT
    t.ID,
    [Date] = MIN(CASE WHEN rnForDate = 1 THEN [Date] END),
    Comment = MIN(CASE WHEN rnForComment = 1 THEN Comment END)
FROM (
    SELECT *,
        rnForDate = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTIION BY t.ID ORDER BY t.Priority DESC, t.Created ASC),
        rnForComment = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTIION BY t.ID ORDER BY t.Priority ASC, t.Created ASC)
    FROM tableA t
    WHERE t.Code IN ('CodeA', 'CodeP')
) t
GROUP BY t.ID;
```

Comment: Thanks , I will try these.

Comment: Ok, hmm, as mentioned in the second requirement, I need  different codes in the different result columns, fx. for column Date its codeA/CodeP but for column Comment -> CodeB